# What to do when the organizers close the submission portal earlier than what was announced?

Tags: publications, conference, deadlines

I was submitting the camera-ready version of my paper to a conference in China, and its deadline was by the end of Sept. 7th based on Pacific daylight time. But, they closed the submission portal at 16:00 (PT) Sept. 7th.

I already contacted the program chairs (which are Professors of Chinese Universities), but I have not heard anything back from them. I imagined they have closed the webpage (maybe by automatic settings) according to their local time in China which is more than half a day ahead of PT. But the conference website (keydates) clearly says that all the deadlines are **at 11:59PM Pacific Daylight Time**.

**Update:** After exchanging a couple of emails they noticed it was a technical problem from the web service they were using for submission management. They solved it eventually and now everyone is happy! :D

So, what can I do instead of giving up on my paper?

Comment: In future, plan to be more ahead of the deadline - avoids this type of issue "I was trying to submit 10 seconds/minutes before it closed" is often heard from students...

Comment: @SolarMike You are right. I always try to do such as far as I can. But this time I was at least 4 hours ahead of the deadline. :D

Comment: Check also, e.g. by phone, whether or not the program chairs really received your email: it's not uncommon (or at least it was just a few years ago) that emails from foreign countries got blocked by the Chinese government.

Comment: If it's a decent conference, there is hope, since the PC chairs will want to make up for their mistake. If they don't, the conference probably wasn't that great to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expecting them to be checking their emails on a weekend is a bit presumptuous. It is Monday now in China, give them a chance to have a coffee, get through some admin, and then deal with their inbox. You may not be the only one emailing to complain.

Comment: I cross my fingers on that assumption! :D

Comment: In case I haven't heard from them in a day from now, should I send an email to the steering committee of the conference?

Comment: Since this is a camera-ready, can you email it (with the extra details) to the publisher in charge (if one has been in contact with you)? This sort of deadline is likely more flexible — the paper's already accepted, it's now a matter of typesetting it in time.